# vitest global variables in setupfiles

Tags: javascript, vitest

How do I get variables defined in my setup files to work in my test files?

Setup files:

```
var lol = 'lol'
```

test:

```
describe("test", () => {
  it("test lol", () => {
    expect(lol).toBe("lol");
  });
});
```

This does not work as expected. However

```
window.lol = 'lol'
```

This works. Is there any way to get the former version to work or automatically set all global variables to be properties of window?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you check out the vitetest test suites:

**https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/tree/main/test/global-setup**

You'll see an example where they use the `setupFiles` in the `test` config to specifically attach values to `global` (specifically with the `beforeAll` hook); note that each tests suite uses its own context which is why it is done this way (as opposed to through the `globalSetup` field of the config).

For example to add `lol`:

```
// vite.config.js
export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    // ...
    setupFiles: ['./src/utils/setup-teardown-hooks.js'],
    // ...
  },
});
```

And then:

```
// setup-teardown-hook.js
import { afterAll, beforeAll } from 'vitest';
beforeAll(() => {
  global.lol = '';
});
afterAll(() => {
  delete global.lol
});
```

Edit: It looks like alternatively you can also use the `populateGlobal` utility function through [Vitest - Custom Environment](https://vitest.dev/guide/environment.html#custom-environment) :

> Vitest also provides populateGlobal utility function, which can be
> used to move properties from object into the global namespace:

Comment: +1 - thanks so much. And for those curious, for node you would use `populateGlobal(global, { lol: '' })` and browser `populateGlobal(window, { lol: '' })`

Comment: Where exactly can I insert this populateGlobal?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @antoineMoPa. @AchiPapakon in your script(s)* that you pass as the config's `setupFiles` key. See the link at the top ([Github vite-test](https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/tree/main/test/global-setup)) and [Vitest Dev Github Comments](https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/issues/1961#issuecomment-1236084872).

Answer (score -2):

If you are going to use global variables only for the setup of a browser env, you can use the building solution:

1. Install `happy-dom` by your favorite package manager

```
$ yarn add -D happy-dom
```

2. Setup configuration in the `vite.config.js`

```
export default defineConfig({
...
    test: {
        environment: 'happy-dom',
        globals: true,
    },
...

});
```

Ref to [doc](https://vitest.dev/guide/environment.html#test-environment).